# Find the smallest positive integer C such that $x$, $y$ and $z$ are all integers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am given the system:

$2x + y = C\\3y + z = C\\x - 4z = C$

$C$ is a constant. Find the smallest positive integer $C$ such that $ x, y$ and $ z$ are all integers.

I have no idea how to go about this... Should I work with the system's augmented matrix and reduce it to echelon form then try to solve it? Is there a different way? This is supposed to be a very elementary question but I just have no idea how to do it... Please Help...

Comment: You could just see whether $C=1$ works, and if it doesn't then try $C=2$, $C=3$, and so on, until you find one that works.

Comment: If i do this by trial and error, how will i know whether x, y and z are all integers? @GerryMyerson

Comment: C=0 works just fine.

Comment: You solve the system with $C=1$. If the solutions are integers, you win. If not, you solve the system with $C=2$. And so on. Mind you, it could take a while to get to a value of $C$ that works – but on the way there, you might notice something that reduces your work considerably. Anyway, when you're faced with a math problem, the most important thing is to DO SOMETHING. So, you know how to solve the system with $C=1$, right? DO IT!

Comment: @Piyush, zero is not a positive integer.

Comment: How do I prove that? This is an 8 mark question and I have no idea what kind of calculations I can do to show that if, for example, C=0 x, y and z will also be integers? @PiyushDivyanakar

Comment: Holy cow. If $C=0$ (which isn't allowed, but never mind), blind Freddy can see that $x=y=z=0$ is a solution!

Comment: The question says $x,y,z$ are integers it doesn't say anything about being positive.

Comment: I still do not understand how I will know that x,y,z are integers if I just substitute values into C? In the 2nd equation there is 3y... this means that y can be a third and z can be 2 and then 3y + z will still equal 3. This makes C an integer but not y? @GerryMyerson

Comment: There are many ways to do this, depending on what you know. You can use the augmented matrix, if you know how, to find that the result is $C = 23$. However, the important part is how to get this result and how to argue that this is the smallest integer for that everything works. Here, some ideas of your own might be nice. Tell us where you get stuck, what you tried, etc. and there might be a way to solve it.

Comment: I have tried substituting many values. That was my initial thought on how to solve this. I get stuck with how do I know for sure that x, y and z are integers when substituting a value for C. As I explained in a previous comment, I have had various cases where I substitute an integer for C and everything looks as if it works. But then I try substituting different fractions into x, y and z in each equation to try and show that they cannot be fractions, but then I  end up getting the same integer value that I substituted into C @DirkLiebhold

Comment: Can you solve for $x,y,z$ while keeping $C$ variable, e.g. something like $x = C/5$, $y = 2C/7$, etc?

Comment: I get x = 7C/23, y = 9C/23 and z = -4C/23... I just don't know what to do wiht these values @DirkLiebhold

Comment: Nevermind, I got it!!! Thank you so much @DirkLiebhold your patience is appreciated

Comment: Good. Now that you got it, let me encourage you to write it up and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

By using the augmented matrix of this system and reducing the matrix to reduced row echelon form, you have:

$\begin{matrix}\\1\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ = \frac{7}{23}C\\
0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 1\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ = \frac{9}{23}C\\
0\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 1 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ = - \frac{4}{23}C\end{matrix}$

This shows that $x = \frac{7}{23}C\\  y = \frac{9}{23}C\\   z = -\frac{4}{23}C$

Therefore 23 is the smallest possible positive integer that $C$ can be for $x, y $ and $z$ to all be integers, since all 3 fractions have 23 as a denominator, multiplying each fraction by 23 will give an integer as an answer. Since 23 is also a prime number, there is no smaller positive integer that will give the same result.

Answer (score 0):

HINT.-The better seems to be solve the easy system so you have
$$x=\frac{7C}{23}\\y=\frac{9C}{23}\\z=\frac{-4C}{23}$$ It is clear now the answer.

Comment: Can I ask @Piquito how you did your Augmented Matrix to achieve your x,y,z/23 answers.
Trying to do this question myself. I am still new to Linear Algebra.